# Selecting columns by regex created from different frame

Tags: r, regex

I want to select by regex a number of columns from a data frame. The problem is, I want to use pairs of words stored in another frame to do so. To be more specific, column names of mycounts data frame:

```
aa1 aa2 aa3 bb1 bb2 bb3 ff1 ff2 ff3 cc1 cc2 cc3 dd1 dd2 dd3
```

and I want to extract to separate frames following pairs (mypairs):

```
aa bb
aa cc
bb cc
cc dd
dd ff
```

where aa and bb denote starting patter for columns to select from mycounts.

I can get stuff manually putting desired patterns like this:

```
tmpdf <- subset(mycounts.test, select=(names(mycounts)[grep('^aa|^bb',names(mycounts))]))
```

do something with tmpdf
select next pair from mypairs
extract columns from mycounts
do again the same thing with tmpdf etc.

but it will be good to always have pattern of output columns enforced by mypairs. With "|" in grep instead of getting dd then ff columns I have it ff then dd. So I am doing:

```
tmpdf1 <- subset(mycounts.test, select=(names(mycounts)[grep('^dd',names(mycounts))]))
tmpdf2 <- subset(mycounts.test, select=(names(mycounts)[grep('^ff',names(mycounts))]))
tmpdf <- cbind(tmpdf1, tmpdf2))
```

Most importantly, naive constructing regex from just first column of mypairs does not work:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mypairs)) { foo <- paste('^', mypairs[i,1], sep=""); print(grep(foo, mycounts)) }
```

This where I am stuck. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Andrie: sorry did post it and reformatted it right away but I was not fast enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not use the `names` function in the last command:

Replace

```
print(grep(foo, mycounts))
```

with

```
print(grep(foo, names(mycounts)))
```